# docker-compose run will not cause race condition?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am doing docker-compose project, which contain a django app and MySQL server. The step of testing is to set up the MySQL server first and then trigger the django app to connect with, but sometimes when I am doing the test in CircleCI, it will cause some race condition.

It means the Django App cannot connect with MySQL server because the MySQL server is not ready yet.

However, when I was using `docker-compose run api make test`, the race condition problem just disappear.

### [Original version]

The code will cause race condition, (api is the container name of django app)

```sh
docker-compose up -d
docker exec api make test
```

### [New version]

Use docker-compose run only, works well

```sh
docker-compose run api make test
```

I think `docker-compose run api make test` will configure the dependency first and run the container `api`, but I think even the **original version** act the same actually. I am wondering why the result it different.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

You can do the same using `depend_on` flag in your docker-compose file but it will not guarantee you that DB will able to handle the connection but it will run the container just in order.

**depends_on**

> Express dependency between services, Service dependencies cause the
>   following behaviours:
>
> - docker-compose up starts services in dependency order. In the
>     following example, db and redis are started before web.
> - docker-compose up SERVICE automatically includes SERVICE’s
>     dependencies. In the following example, docker-compose up web also
>     creates and starts db and redis.
> - docker-compose stop stops services in dependency order. In the
>     following example, web is stopped before db and redis.

**Simple example:**

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  web:
    build: .
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis
  redis:
    image: redis
  db:
    image: postgres
```

This is one way but it will not wait for DB status where DB able to accept the connection, it will just start in order so you can control the order in docker-compose but what if the DB is not ready and your application try to connect and failed to established connection?

> The problem of waiting for a database (for example) to be ready is really just a  subset of a much larger problem of distributed systems.
>   In production, your database could become unavailable or move hosts at
>   any time. Your application needs to be resilient to these types of
>   failures. To handle this, design your application to attempt to
>   re-establish a connection to the database after a failure. If the
>   application retries the connection, it can eventually connect to the
>   database.

The best solution is to perform this check-in your application code, both at startup and whenever a connection is lost for any reason. However, if you don’t need this level of resilience, you can work around the problem with a wrapper script:

Use a tool such as [wait-for-it](https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it), [dockerize](https://github.com/jwilder/dockerize), or sh-compatible [wait-for](https://github.com/Eficode/wait-for). These are small wrapper scripts which you can include in your application’s image to poll a given host and port until it’s accepting TCP connections.

For example, to use wait-for-it.sh or wait-for to wrap your service’s command

```
version: "2"
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "80:8000"
    depends_on:
      - "db"
    command: ["./wait-for-it.sh", "db:5432", "--", "python", "app.py"]
  db:
    image: postgres
```

However these scripts and tools may help in some cases or may not but the best way to manage is a health check or retry logic the application or application should able to handle such condition if DB is not available it does not mean the application will set back and throw exception but should be a way to retry to establish connection and resilient to handle such cases.

You can explore the mentioned tool and offical documentation of docker [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/) and [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/).